# Return Alamofire responseDecodable result within a function to a global constant

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am attempting to call AF.request(*my api*).responseDecodable within a function that I will reuse to populate global constants at app startup. I try to return the value of the decoded response but this does not work because the alamofire request is asynchronous, and the return statement happens before the callback:

```
func getImageNames(forEndpoint endpoint: String) -> [String] {
var imageNameArray: [String] = []
AF.request("http://\(serverIP)\(endpoint)")
    .responseDecodable(of: [String].self) { response in
        imageNameArray = response.value ?? []
        print(imageNameArray)
    }
print(imageNameArray)
return imageNameArray
```

}

and then calling it in a different swift file:

```
let coverImageNames: [String] = getImageNames(forEndpoint: "/api/offerings/marketing/coverImages")
```

As expected, this first prints (and returns) an empty array [], and then prints the desired result, the array of image names I want from the server.

I am wondering how I can change this code in order to return the result I want. I have tried async/await but that has 2 issues, 1) when trying to *await* the *AF.request*, "No 'async' operations occur within 'await' expression", and 2) "'async' call cannot occur in a global variable initializer".

I have also tried changing *coverImageNames* to a var and updating it in the *responseDecodable* callback, but this is confusing, makes the function not reusable, and requires updating all of my views after the callback has run.

I also tried putting the view where I am using the *coverImageNames* array within the callback and returning a view, but I never got it to work, this is even messier, and I foresee it resulting in callback hell as I continue to develop this app further.

I need to use all of this data from the server within the app to populate my home page and elsewhere, which is why I am trying to put it in global constants at startup. Any idea on how to return this value after the request is finished and use it everywhere within the project after it has been returned (and maybe a brief explanation on why everything I see on StackOverflow says not to use global constants at all)? Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at this official link, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app:  
[Managing model data in your app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app)

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine thanks, looks like i had totally the wrong approach to using server data in my app